# How to check if a process is running?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am making an injector. I want to know if a process is running, and if not then I want to download a file. I have done the downloading of a file. Now I just need to know how to check if a process is running.

Comment: I'd rephrase your question as "how to check if a process is running in Windows" and check out [Process Status API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/_psapi/) and search in SO `EnumProcesses`

Comment: See [Process Enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/procthread/process-enumeration) on MSDN, with an emphasis on [Enumerating All Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/psapi/enumerating-all-processes) and [Taking a Snapshot and Viewing Processes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/toolhelp/taking-a-snapshot-and-viewing-processes)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.